# How do I make pointers work?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, printf

I have 2 functions. The first function called "chooser" which scans in 10 numbers into an array, and prints out 3 numbers from that array. The second function called "calculator" determines 3 numbers should be printed out. However, I think I've done something wrong with the pointers?

```
void chooser() {
    int cool_array[10] = {'\0'};

    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10) {
        scanf("%d", &cool_array[i]);
        i++;
    }

    int first_num = 0;
    int second_num = 0;
    int third_num = 0;
    calculator(cool_array, first_num, second_num, third_num);

    printf("%d %d %d\n", first_num, second_num, third_num);
}

void calculator(int cool_array[],
            int *first_num, int *second_num, int *third_num) {

    int one = cool_array[0];
    int two = cool_array[1];
    int _three = cool_array[2];

    // I want the code below to change the number of first_num,
    // second_num and third_num in the chooser function, so it
    // can print the new numbers determined by the calculator function
    first_num = &one;
    second_num = &two;
    third_num = &three;
}
```

Comment: `int cool_array[10] = {'\0'};` is the same as simply `int cool_array[10] = {0};` Why? 2 reasons. 1st the *nul_character* has a value of `0`. Second when you provide array initialization with only a single element, e.g. `{'x'}` only the 1st element is set to `x`, all other elements are set to `0`. So a single initializer only sets the 1st element and zeros the rest. Try it, e.g. `int cool_array[10] = {1};` and then check (or output) each element.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I only did `int cool_array[10] = {'\0'};` so it didn't give me an error. at the end of the day, the user enters 10 numbers (no matter what they enter 10 nunbers), so it doesn't matter. The array holds 10 numbers before it even prints it anything

Comment: It was right -- I just wanted to make sure you understood you were just setting the 1st element and zeroing the rest. Many new users think `{'x'}` initializes ALL elements to `'x'`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yep, I knew. However, do you know how to fix the pointer thing? How do I make my calculator function, change the first_num in the chooser function? The array prints out the user inputted data (I checked).

Comment: `calculator(cool_array, first_num, second_num, third_num);` to `calculator(cool_array, &first_num, &second_num, &third_num);` because `calculator` is expecting *pointer to* `int` as the 2nd, 3rd & 4th arguments. Then `*first_num = one;` and so on. (not `first_num = &one;`) Since `first_num` is already a pointer and you want to set the value at *the address pointed to* by `first_num`, you must *dereference* it to assign it a value. `one` in declared local to `calculator`, so it is destroyed when `calculator` **returns**. You can't assign its address to `first_num`...

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is to take a reference of the 3 variables to change them in the 'calculator' function
you can just define the function as:

```
void calculator(int cool_array[], int &first_num, int &second_num, int &third_num)
```

Then of course you don't need to use the dereference operator down in the calculator function, just say *first_num = one* and you'll be changing the original variable.

Comment: Didn't work. Just gave me an error. it says "Expected '('. So I thought I missed a '('. However, I did not. I did it my way the same way as I posted above, and it worked. So this way doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As expressed in my comment above, `calculator` takes pointers to `int` as shown below:

```
void chooser() {
    <snip>

    int first_num = 0;
    int second_num = 0;
    int third_num = 0;

    // calculator(cool_array, first_num, second_num, third_num);
    /* the above is incorrect because calculator expacts a pointer to
     * int as its 2nd, 3rd, and 4th values. It must be called as:
     */
    calculator(cool_array, &first_num, &second_num, &third_num);

    printf("%d %d %d\n", first_num, second_num, third_num);
}
```

Above was a simple syntactical issue that would be caught by any compiler and an error thrown, but now we are to the heart of your problem. `one, two, three` are declared local to `calculator` and there values (and addresses) are not available after `calculator` **returns** and any attempt to access either after they have gone out of scope is *Undefined Behavior*. (your code could appear to run as intended or `SegFault` or anything in between) Look at the comments below:

```
void calculator(int cool_array[],
            int *first_num, int *second_num, int *third_num) {

    int one = cool_array[0];    /* so far so good, you assign values from */
    int two = cool_array[1];    /* cool_array to one, two and three       */
    int three = cool_array[2];  /* ('_names' are generally reserved)      */

    // I want the code below to change the number of first_num,
    // second_num and third_num in the chooser function, so it
    // can print the new numbers determined by the calculator function

    /* BIG PROBLEM, one, two, and three are decalred local to calculator,
       when calculator returns, the function stack memory (where local 
       variables are stored) is released for reuse by your program and any
       attempt to access addresses within the function stack after the
       function returns is Undefined Behavior -- (really bad)
    first_num = &one;
    second_num = &two;
    third_num = &three;
    */

    /* assign the value to the address 'pointed to' (held) by each */
    *first_num = one;
    *second_num = two;
    *third_num = three;
}
```

Further, look at what you were attempting to do. `first_num = &one;` assigns the *address of* `one` to `first_num`. We have discussed the problem with the *address of* `one`, but there is another fundamental problem. `first_num` in `calculator` is a **copy of** the pointer `first_num` in `chooser`. The copy in `calculator` has its very own (and very different) address. If `one` had a storage duration that survived the return of `calculator` you still would not see any change to `first_num` in `chooser`. Why? because in `calculator` you merely changed a copy of the pointer from `chooser`.

However, while `first_num` in `calculator` is a copy, the **address it holds as its value** is the very same as the pointer in `chooser`. So if you set the value at the address **pointed to** by `first_num` (by dereferencing it and assigning the value), then that change will be reflected back in `chooser`. That is how pointers work (and how *pass-by-value* C function parameters work).

Now lets do what you are attempting.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* let's put the functions in the right order (or use prototypes) */

void calculator(int cool_array[],
            int *first_num, int *second_num, int *third_num) {

    int one = cool_array[0];
    int two = cool_array[1];
    int three = cool_array[2];

    /* set the value at the address held by each poiter to wanted values */
    *first_num = one;
    *second_num = two;
    *third_num = three;
}

void chooser() {
    int cool_array[10] = {0};

    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10) {
        scanf("%d", &cool_array[i]);
        i++;
    }

    int first_num = 0;
    int second_num = 0;
    int third_num = 0;
    /* a proper call to calculator */
    calculator(cool_array, &first_num, &second_num, &third_num);

    printf("%d %d %d\n", first_num, second_num, third_num);
}

int main (void) {

    chooser();
    return 0;
}
```

(it's also a good idea to prompt for input so your user isn't just sitting there staring at a blinking cursor wondering if your program has hung...)

**Example Use Output**

```
$ ./bin/choose
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
10 20 30
```

of if you prefer a piped example which generates the same numbers and automatically feeds it to your program:

```
$ printf "%s\n" {10..100..10} | ./bin/choose
10 20 30
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.